# Typecasting A<X,Y> to A<Object,Object>

Tags: java, spring, generics, casting, guava

I am trying to implement Guava Cache.

My Cache Object is :

```
Cache<String,MyObject> cache = initCache();
```

And GuavaCache constructor looks like:

```
GuavaCache(String name, com.google.common.cache.Cache<Object, Object>    cache)
```

Doing this:

```
GuavaCache options = new GuavaCache("guava_cache",cache);
```

gives error:

```
Cache<String,OptionMap> cannot be converted to Cache<Object,Object>
```

I have tried `<Object,Object> cache` but it doesnot work.

Cache is an interface:

```
public interface Cache<K, V>
```

GuavaCache: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/guava/GuavaCache.html

this is what initCache does:

```
return CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterAccess(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, MyObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public MyObject load(String key) throws Exception {

                        return new MyObject(loadFromRedis());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Is GuavaCache a class defined by you? It would be helpful to see how it uses the cache object it is given, particularly if it needs to read or,write to it or both.

Comment: Due to type erasure the types `Cache<String, MyObject>` and `Cache<Object, Object>` look alike at runtime. Thus, you should be able to simply cast your cache to `Cache<Object, Object>`: e.g. `new GuavaCache("guava_cache", (Cache<Object, Object>) cache)`. But be aware that you're losing type safety due to this.

Comment: @TillRohrmann : I am not able to convert it.Getting error Cannot cast Cache<String,MyObject> to Cache<Object,Object>

Comment: If he is using Spring's GuavaCache he probably doesn't care about type safety.

Comment: I solved it by typecasting it to (Cache).

Comment: @lliBtheLizard having realized `GuavaCache` is Spring's and not yours (should have read the comments, d'oh), I've updated my answer with an example of why casting is bad in this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that your `Cache<String, MyObject> cache` is *not* a `Cache<Object, Object>` and so you can't pass it to a constructor that requires `Cache<Object, Object>`.

The underlying problem here is that Spring's `GuavaCache` is not primarily a wrapper around a Guava `Cache`, rather it is an implementation of Spring's [`Cache`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) interface that happens to be backed by a Guava `Cache`.

The distinction might be a bit subtle, but the important point is that the contract you're dealing with is Spring's `Cache`, and this interface allows you to use any `Object`s as keys and values - see [`put(Object, Object)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html#put-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-).

Therefore if you want to use Spring's `GuavaCache`, you are required to pass it a Guava `Cache` object that allows any `Object`s for keys and values. But your `Cache<String, MyObject>` doesn't allow this.
The library isn't broken, it's deliberately coded this way to stop you passing the wrong type of cache into the constructor, and that's why your code won't compile.

You have seen that you can fudge it by casting your cache to a raw Guava `Cache`, but then what happens if someone does this?

```
options.put("key","not a MyObject"); // appears to work fine

MyObject item = cache.get("key"); // throws a ClassCastException
```

If you really want to use `GuavaCache` you should respect its contract, and give it a backing object that supports the operations defined in `Cache`. For example:

```
Cache<Object, Object> cache;
```

and

```
Cache<Object, Object> initCache() {
    return CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterAccess(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build(new CacheLoader<Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object load(Object key) throws Exception {
                 return new MyObject(loadFromRedis());
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a final solution which work.I have also included my initCache.

Comment: @lliBtheLizard added an example. It's not ideal to be using `Cache<Object, Object>`, but it's forced by the contract of `GuavaCache`

Comment: Cache is abstract,So last two lines wont work. As a matter, the last implementation of CacheManager in [link] https://dzone.com/articles/spring-caching-abstraction-and also doesnot work.Any reasons why?

Comment: @lliBtheLizard I've rewritten the answer a bit - please note the bit about "a wrapper around a Guava Cache" vs "an implementation of Spring `Cache`". Maybe the answer is you should be using Spring's methods rather than Guava's to populate the cache. Either way, if it's a Spring `Cache` you want to deal with, you should be starting with a `Cache<Object,Object>`.

Answer (score -1):

Since you cannot have type safety, I would just use raw types.

```
Cache cache = initCache();
new GuavaCache("guava_cache",cache);
```

Comment: Care to explain the reason for the downvote? Reading the comments it's also what the author ended up doing

Comment: You're unlikely to get an answer to this - most drive-by downvoters don't come back. I didn't downvote, but I'd imagine the reason is that this solution "fools" Java into passing something that's not a `Cache<Object,Object>` in a parameter of that type. At the very least, the parameter type in `GuavaCache` should be changed to reflect what the constructor actually wants as a parameter, which is *not* `Cache<Object,Object>`

Comment: Generics are erased at runtime, so omitting them as an impact only during compilation an no code outside of GuavaCache can ever need to use the object. The problem here is that the library forced `Object` when they wanted `?`. Omitting generics is the only reasonable approach apart from stop using that library.

Comment: but casting is *still* wrong - the OP should have created his cache object as `Cache<Object,Object>` in the first place

Comment: He didn't tell if this is his only use of initCache. Better to renounce to type safety only when dealing with the broken library call and leave the rest of his code safe

Comment: the library is new to me, but I see it contains `put(Object, Object)` which is now going to allow arbitrary key/value pairs to be put in his generic list, potentially causing a world of pain. Relying on type erasure is almost never the right answer. Probably "don't use GuavaCache" is the best advice

Comment: There is no way to put the wrong pair in a `<Object,Object>`. The library really uses raw types it's just declaring the wrong contructor

Comment: But it's not an `<Object, Object>` - the `put("key","value")` will work, but `MyObject mo = cache.get("key")` will then bomb.